# `importScript` unable to resolve dependency before serviceWorker push event

Tags: javascript, push-notification, es6-promise, service-worker, web-push

Unable to resolve dependency using `importScript` before `serviceWorker` push promise resolved; can somebody suggest better way to get this sorted?

**ServiceWorker `fetch` event:**

```
var iDB; // Global Variable
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(e) {
    self.importScripts("dexie.min.js");
    var o = new Dexie('database_name');
    o.version(1).stores({
        iDBStore: "++id,adspotkey"
        iDB = o
    });
});
```

**Service Worker `push` Event**

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(getDetails().then(function(ex) {
        try {
            e = wpSDK.iDB;
            return e.iDBStore.where("id").above(0).toArray().then(function(ox) {
                console.log(ox);
            }
        }));
});
```

**Note:**

- On `push` console throws Error as shown below
  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'iDBStore' of undefined(…)`
- Using [Wrapper for IndexedDB - Dexie.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `importScripts` on the background like this.

```
self.importScripts("dexie.min.js");
var iDB; // Global Variable
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(e) {
    var o = new Dexie('database_name');
    o.version(1).stores({
        iDBStore: "++id,adspotkey"
        iDB = o
    });
});
```

`importScripts` is a synchronous method. As a result, when you run this method on background, it will block ServiceWorker from being active until the script is completely loaded.

Comment: Thanks Tresdin - I will definitely try your suggestion!